# WPF user control in two versions

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I need to create user control (or something else) that takes model and based on a property of that model it changes how it looks like. I need it to have minimized and extended versions of same item.

some elements are missing and some change size. Most probably I need to define two data templates but I do not know how to use this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic content of a Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469504/dynamic-content-of-a-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do you:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="firstView" Visibility="{Binding firstViewActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <!-- First view xaml goes here -->
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="secondView" Visibility="{Binding firstViewActive, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <!-- Second view xaml goes here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

You'd need to implement the converters, something like this:

```
    public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }



    public class InvertedBoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return !(value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return !(value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
        }
    }
```